# Sails response data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, response

Sails returns an object with this data:

{data: Object, status: 201, config: Object, statusText: "Created"}

And in "data" attribute the result of API. I would like to return only result of my API without this object, like if I have done response.data.

Thank you and sorry about my english

Comment: Can you add some of your code? Like part of Controller and Model that is generating it.

Comment: Please elaborate as I really wanted to help but I can't get what you are trying to accomplish